# Memory run out when using laravel brainsocket

Tags: php, sockets, laravel, websocket

When I use `php artisan brainsocket:start --port=8080` to start the socket server, and when user grown gradually, my memory always run out and the socket server will stop.

```
PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 33151019 bytes) 
in /alidata/www/wcketbtn/vendor/react/stream/src/Buffer.php on line 118
{"error":{"type":"Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalErrorException",
"message":"Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 33151019 bytes)",
"file":"\/alidata\/www\/wketbtn\/vendor\/react\/stream\/src\/Buffer.php","line":118}}
```

As user grown I use `htop` to check memory usage:

```
 CPU[||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||99.3%]     Tasks: 64, 57 thr; 2 running
  Mem[||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||636/994MB]     Load average: 1.00 0.68 0.37 
  Swp[                                                    0/0MB]     Uptime: 123 days(!), 19:05:51

  PID USER      PRI  NI  VIRT   RES   SHR S CPU% MEM%   TIME+  Command
28858 root       20   0  202M 91680  6776 R 97.0  9.0  5:54.93 php artisan brainsocket:start --port=8080
29054 root       20   0 24508  2184  1448 R  1.0  0.2  0:00.06 htop
```

So I use `php -d memory_limit=512M artisan brainsocket:start --port=8080` but still will run out memory.

I couldn't figure out which code increase my memory usage gradully, and how I can limit it or maybe unset something. How can I do?

Alternatively, how can I write a shell script that can monitor the socket server down, when it stop, restart it ( run `php artisan brainsocket:start --port=8080` ).

Answer (score 0):

The [memory_get_usage](https://php.net/manual/en/function.memory-get-usage.php) and [memory_get_peak_usage](https://php.net/manual/en/function.memory-get-peak-usage.php) functions are your friend.

Try saving their output somewhere after various other parts of your PHP script and you will pinpoint the problem in no time.

Also I would check that your `memory_limit=512M` was actually working. What does the error code look like when you have that set? Does it still say ~134,000,000 bytes exhausted?